# django migrations does not update database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have django app already online and running. I created new model and if I do the makemigrations, it is working fine, but if I want to migrate it, then I receive `Running migrations:No migrations` to apply. Even though that I made a change. The change is also in the migration file. I am using postgresql with it. I tried to delete the migration file and create it once more, but it did not help. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you **sure** that the migration is not applied yet? Did you check the database?

Comment: Yes I did, the two tables are missing there. Even in the admin menu I try to add a record it throws server error (500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some migrations are marked as applied incorrectly in the database. This can be solved by using the [`--fake` flag [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) to mark an appropriate migration as applied / some migrations as unapplied.

Suppose that your app is named `myapp` and the migration `0004` is **applied properly** to the database (you are trying to apply `0005` or further which doesn't work) then you will run the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0004 --fake
```

> **Note**: `myapp` and `0004` is an example, do this according to your apps name and which migrations are applied.

**Edit**: It appears that you have deleted the migrations. But thankfully have some version control in place. Best would be to get the migration files back from the version control. If for some reason you are unable to do that, revert the models to how they were before their changes and make sure no migration files exist for now. Next generate the migration files by running `makemigrations` (check that they are as expected and your database state corresponds to these generated files). Next run the following two commands:

```
python manage.py migrate <appname> zero --fake
python manage.py migrate <appname> --fake
```

The first one will mark all migrations as unapplied for the app. The second one will mark all the migrations as applied. Next you will add the changes you wanted to make back to the models and migrate again.

Comment: I deleted all previous 000X files. There is no way to recover, right?

Comment: @pipikej Do you know the changes you have made exactly? And can you revert your models code back to how it was? Perhaps do you have some version control (git, etc.)?

Comment: Yes I do have a git, and yes I can revert the changes to previous versions.

Comment: @pipikej check my edit. Best if you can get the migration files from the version control.